# Is possible to change the server flying flag without restarting it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-forge

On the `server.properties` file, there is this configuration value called `allow-flight` with a default value of `false`. According to the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Server.properties):

> Allows users to use flight on your server while in Survival mode, if they have a mod that provides flight installed.
> With allow-flight enabled, griefers will possibly be more common, because it will make their work easier. In Creative mode this has no effect.

> - false - Flight is not allowed (players in air for at least 5 seconds will be kicked).
> - true - Flight is allowed, and used if the player has a fly mod installed.

Can this value be edited without restarting the server? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In vanilla, no.

Changes to the `server.properties` files always require a restart to take effect, because the server loads its content only at the start. There is no other way around it, unless there is a mod or Bukkit/Spigot plugin to temporarily store the new value until the server is restarted.

Comment: Note that the question has the [tag:minecraft-forge] tag. But I doubt that Forge alone changes that.

Comment: @FabianRöling yes, Forge doesn't allow that either. It would still require an addon.

Comment: Well, that is sad. I guess that the only option is to search for a Forge plugin/mod.

Answer (score -1):

```
@EventHandler
public void on(PlayerJoinEvent e) {

    Player p = e.getPlayer();
    p.setAllowFlight(false);
    p.setFlying(false);

}
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Arqade! Can you provide context to the code here, such as what it does, and where you would place it?